# How many min-cut is in Tree without weights?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

I‌ read an example from one book that take from a 2013-local-contest about Algorithms.

Who can say, how we can calculate this question?

> How many min-cut is in Tree without weights, with `n` vertex and `n-1`
>   edges?

any idea or hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the minimum cut is one and there are exactly `n - 1` such cuts(we can cut any edge of the tree and obtain two non-empty components).

Why is it the case?
The size of the minimum cut is one and it cannot be smaller because the graph is connected. Now we can remove one edge. Removing one edge uniquely determines two sets of vertices and we have `n - 1` edges. Thus, we have `n - 1` minimum cuts.

Comment: please add some detail :)‌ you are expert.

Comment: @DioIli What is exactly unclear? The size of the minimum cut is one and it cannot be smaller because the graph is connected. Now we can remove one edge. Removing one edge uniquely determines two sets of vertices and we have `n - 1` edges. Thus, we have `n - 1` minimum cuts.

Comment: aha, yes, please add it to your answer and I‌ approve... thanks

Comment: This answer is of course correct, but it could have been so much better in the form of some *hints*.  "Suppose you delete one edge.  Is the tree still connected?  What does this tell you about the size of the smallest possible cut?  Would any edge work?  How many edges are there?"

Comment: nice question, but your answer dosent have any proof? @kraskevich how we can proof it ?

Comment: @user4249446 There is almost nothing to prove here. It directly follows from the definition of  a tree and a min cut.

Comment: it not well-defined for me but +1. maybe with an illustration or example it make more clearer. thanks; @kraskevich